# scaffold is not taking my bootstrap css

Tags: css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass, stylesheet

I'm a begginer working with ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0] and rails: 4.0.4. I generated a scaffold without `css` file with

```
rails g  scaffold dreams dream:string whant:string offer:string need:string --skip-stylesheets
```

Im working with `bootstrap`. Rails generated the `scaffold`, but the problem is that this doesn't take my bootstrap css `bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss` Any sugestion?

Comment: we would need to see some code - for example, how you're including the bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Hi guys!Thanks! fortunately i solved the problem!